# JSON access object within object with different names

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble working with a JSON sample data. I have the following JSON object:

```
var classList =
    [
      {
        'class1': {
            'name': 'physics',
            'year': '2015'
          }
        }, {
        'class2': {
            'name': 'geography',
            'year': '2016'
          }
        }, {
        'class3': {
            'name': 'history',
            'year': '2015'
          }
        }, {
        'class4': {
            'name': 'math',
            'year': '2016'
        }
      }
    ]
```

I want to reiterate over each object of classList and get the 'name' value. I was trying something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < classList.length; i += 1) {
    if (classList[i] !== undefined) {
        returnVal = classList[i][0]['name'];
    }
}
```

But, this doesn't seem to be working. The problem is the classList has further objects of different name 'class1', 'class2', 'class3' & 'class4'. I am not sure how to iterate over them. I don't want to hard code these values.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is duplicate then can you please point me to the original question?

Comment: Up at the top of the question: [Loop through JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: You  might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json as well.

Comment: Thanks. Got my answer